# Solve Kolmogorov differential equations for birth-death process with constant rates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I need to solve the Kolmogorov forward equations for a birth-death process whose birth/death rates $\lambda_k,k=0,\ldots$ and $\mu_k,k=1,\ldots $ are constant, i.e., $\lambda_k=\lambda$ and $\mu_k=\mu$, respectively.

I have formulated the equations as
\begin{eqnarray}
P_n^{'}(t) &=& -(\lambda+\mu)P_n(t)+\lambda P_{n-1}(t)+\mu P_{n+1}(t),\\
P_0^{'}(t) &=& -\lambda P_0(t) + \mu P_1(t),\\
P_0(0) &=& 1,\\
P_n(0) &=& 0,\ n>0.
\end{eqnarray}

May I know if there is an explicit solution for this $P_n(t)$? I need the transition probabilities $P_n(t)$ for arbitrary $n$ and $t$. I understand that the Kolmogorov forward equations are solvable if $\lambda_k=k\lambda$ and $\mu_k=k\mu$ [Kendall1948]. The form of my equations looks good. But I wasn't able to find a solution for the above equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be clear, you want to find $P_n(t)$ for a birth-death process with constant birth rate $q(i,i+1)=\lambda$ and constant death rate $q(i,i-1)=\mu$?

This particular birth and death process is exactly the [$M/M/1$ queue.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue)

As you can see, under "Transient solution", there is a solution for the probability mass function dependent on time for a particular state.